# Go from A to D in three equal steps

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction, constructive-mathematics, plane-geometry

Given two parallel lines $r$ and $s$, line $p$, perpendicular to both, and points $A$ and $D$ on different sides of $p$ with respect to the parallel lines, how can I prove the existence of two points, $B$ and $C$, respectively on $r$ and $s$, such that segments $AB$, $BC$ and $CD$ are congruent?

I'd prefer a constructive proof, for it to be a more general solution useful to solve this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571863/prove-that-every-triangle-is-the-orthogonal-projection-of-an-equilateral-one) too. (also, geometric proofs are fun)

Here are two examples I constructed in reverse (I fitted the lines to the points and not viceversa):
[image: example 1]
[image: example 2]

Answer (score 3):

Let $a,x,d,y$ the distances shown in the picture and $t=\overline{AB}=\overline{BC}=\overline{CD}$

[image]

Then we have

$$a^2+x^2=t^2\tag{1}$$
$$d^2+y^2=t^2\tag{2}$$
$$(x-y)^2+e^2=t^2\tag{3}$$
If we add $a^2d^2$ to  $(3)$ and reorder the terms we get
$$x^2+a^2-2xy+y^2+b^2+e^2=t^2+a^2+d^2$$
an further
$$2xy=t^2+e^2-a^2-d^2\tag{4}$$
if we substitute by $(1)$ and $(2)$.
Squaring $(5)$ and substituting again by $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives
$$4(t^2-a^2)(t^2-d^2)=(t^2+e^2-a^2-d^2)^2\tag{5}$$
$(5)$ is an equation of degree $4$ in $t$ but quadratic in $t^2$:
$$3t^4-2t^2(a^2+d^2+e^2)+(2a^2d^2+2a^2e^2+2d^2e^2)-(a^4+d^4+e^4)=0$$
 So it can be easily solved.
The discriminant $\Delta$  of the quadratic equation satisfies
$$\frac{1}{8}\Delta=(a^2-d^2)^2+(a^2-e^2)^2+(d^2-e^2)^2\ge0$$
For the second picture we could start with the equations

$$a^2+x^2=t^2$$
$$d^2+y^2=t^2$$
$$(x+y)^2+e^2=t^2\tag{6}$$

but we would get the same solutions because the equations differ only in the sign of $y$ in $(6)$

Comment: Hmm, this is great, since I had no proof at all before I asked the question. However I was hoping for a geometric proof. Should I ask a new question or is it fair that I edit this one?

Comment: for me it is ok if you edit your question  in such a way that it does not invalidate my answer, e.g. you can add, that you prefer a geometric proof.

Comment: Are these solutions for $t^2$ real and positive?

Comment: @Michael  At least one solution for $t^2$ is a positive real.  It is also possible to have two positive values for $t^2$.  As far as construction is concerned, it can easily be proven that $t$ is constructible with a straightedge and a compass.  However, the construction seems very tedious.

Comment: @Michael: I didn't check this. But the OP shows that there are triples $(a,d,e)$ where at least one solution exists.